# Invalid \x Escape when loading Spark Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm loading a spark dataframe that is delimited by `"\x0"`. When I run this:

```
logs = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("delimiter", "\x0").load("path")
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid \x escape
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is it meant to be `\x0` or `\x00`? Null char (`chr(0)`) in Python is `\x00`.

Answer (score 1):

As `\` is the escape character in [python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), it is necessary define it as a literal. You can simply put a `r` in front of the string to turn it into a raw string:

```py
logs = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("delimiter", r"\x0").load("path")
```